# how to set url in another input after upload file in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

I am working with react with axios. i am uploading a file in react and i want to set url in another input after file upload but i am unable to get value. in console i am getting value properly but issue in input field. currently i m doing with different method.
i want uploaded file url in id="uploadRhp". please help if anybody know.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

class TradeImportComponent extends React.Component<{},any>{

    // API Endpoints
    custom_file_upload_url = `https://exaample.com/api/ipo/document/upload`;
  canvas: any;

    // state
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.canvas = React.createRef()
        this.state = {
            image_file: null,
            image_preview: '',
            
        }
    }

    // Image Preview Handler
    handleImagePreview = (e) => {
        let image_as_base64 = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
        let image_as_files = e.target.files[0];

        this.setState({
            image_preview: image_as_base64,
            image_file: image_as_files,
        })
    }

    // Image/File Submit Handler
    handleSubmitFile = () => {

        if (this.state.image_file !== null){

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('ipoName', 'tata');
            formData.append('document', this.state.image_file);

            axios.post(
                this.custom_file_upload_url,
                formData,
                {
                    headers: {
                        // "Authorization": "YOUR_API_AUTHORIZATION_KEY_SHOULD_GOES_HERE_IF_HAVE",
                        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                    },                    
                }
            )
            .then(res => {
                console.log(`Success` + res.data.response);
                var json= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data.response));
                console.log(json);
                console.log(json.url);
                console.log(this.canvas.current.value);
                this.canvas.current.value=json.url;
                console.log(this.canvas.current.value);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    }


    // render from here
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                {/* image preview */}
                <img src={this.state.image_preview} alt="image_preview" width="100%"/>
                {this.state.url}
                {/* image input field */}
                <input
                    type="file"
                    onChange={this.handleImagePreview}
                    
                />
                <input type="hidden" name="logo" id="uploadlogo"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="rhp" value="test@1234567" ref={this.canvas} id="uploadRhp"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="financial_Pdf" id="uploadfinancial"/>

                <label>Upload file</label>
                <input type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmitFile} value="Submit"/>

                <ul>
      </ul>


            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TradeImportComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setstate in axios response store the response in state

```
  // state
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.canvas = React.createRef()
            this.state = {
                image_file: null,
                image_preview: '',
                uploadURL:''
                
            }
    }      

  handleSubmitFile = () => {

        if (this.state.image_file !== null){

            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('ipoName', 'tata');
            formData.append('document', this.state.image_file);

          return  axios.post(
                this.custom_file_upload_url,
                formData,
                {
                    headers: {
                        // "Authorization": "YOUR_API_AUTHORIZATION_KEY_SHOULD_GOES_HERE_IF_HAVE",
                        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                    },                    
                }
            )
            .then(res => {
                console.log(`Success` + res.data.response);
                var json= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data.response));
                
               //use setstate
               setState({uploadURL:json.url)
                
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    }

    //in JSX render

    <Input value={this.state.uploadUrl}/>
```

Comment: hi, its working in console.log but unable to get value in input

Comment: have you used setState to store the url?

Comment: yes, you use  setState to store the url

Comment: then you can show the values in the input field, right?

Comment: yes but not working, can u please share me a example.